# Lucee array.each return value

Tags: cfml, lucee

On Lucee 4.5.1.003 I have this function where LineArray is an array of LineItem objects.

```
public function getLineItemDetailsById(required numeric id){
    this.LineArray.each(function(i){
        if(i.Id == id){
            return i;
        }
    });
}
```

The function returns null even if there is a match. If I add a var to hold the found object, the var is returned.

```
public function getLineItemDetailsById(required numeric id){
    var found = '';
    this.LineArray.each(function(i){
        if(i.Id == id){
            found = i;
            //return i;
        }
    });
    return found;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong expecting array.each to return i or am I misunderstanding how array.each works?

Edit: To be clear, the second function does return the found object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look slightly closer at the code in your first example:

```
public function getLineItemDetailsById(required numeric id){ // first function
    this.LineArray.each(function(i){ // second function
        if(i.Id == id){
            return i; // return for second function
        }
    });
    // no return from first function
}
```

I have annotated it slightly to demonstrate your problem. `getLineItemDetailsById()` "returns `null`" because you simply aren't returning anything from it. So if you have:

```
result = getLineItemDetailsById(1);
```

then `getLineItemDetailsById()` is not returning anything, so `result` ends up being `null`.

So that's the problem you're seeing.

Furthermore, you don't want to be using `each()` within that function: one would only use `each()` when you definitely want to iterate over the entire array. In your case it seems like you want to exit as soon as you find a match for `id`.

In which case you want something like this:

```
public function getLineItemDetailsById(required numeric id){
    var matchedElement = null; 
    this.LineArray.some(function(element){
        if(element.Id == id){
            matchedElement = element;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return matchedElement;
}
```

One uses `some()` when one wants to iterate over an array *only until* some criteria is matched. Here I'm leveraging this to set the `matchedElement` when the exit criteria is met.

Comment: Not come across `some` before. Is there any benefit to using a closure in this case over a straightforward `for-in` loop? That would halve the no. of lines and read more clearly:`for( var item in this.LineArray ){
 if( item.id == id )
   return item;
}`

Comment: Using the iterator method specifically intended for the kind of job at hand is clearer in intent than just using a generic loop.

Answer (score 0):

If ID is always expected to exist use:

```
public function getLineItemDetailsById(required numeric id){
    return this.LineArray.Find(function(i){return i.ID==id);});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.each     loops through the entire array and returns void
.reduce   returns a single value after looping through all elements
.some     allows an exit sooner than each
```

(See docs for more methods)

```
for(i in this.lineArray)if(i.id is id) return i; ... avoids some overhead
```

Although a better way, in most cases, is to populate this.lineStruct from this.lineArray, ahead of time.

```
this.lineStruct={}; 
this.lineArray.each(function(i){this.lineStruct[i.id]=i;});
function getLineById(id) 
{   return this.lineStruct.keyexists(id)?this.lineStruct[id]:null;   }
```